# Mac Partitioning Error (-69624)

Tags: linux, macos, mac, partitioning, debian

I'm trying to create a partition on my Mac so I can run Debian, but whenever I try to partition my disk I get this error:

[image]

I've factory reset my Mac, and tried partitioning in recovery mode. I'm not sure what's wrong.